# javascript --- get a new data everytime user press the button and cancel the previous one

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, appendchild

everytime a user press the button I want to overwrite on the `<h1>` to whatever the user insert(in this case will always be a date), instead of keep adding child on the DOM, can someone help  me? here's the code:

```
const header = document.createElement("h1");
header.classList.add("star-sign");
div.appendChild(header);

If ('statement'){header.innerHTML = 'execute'}
```

Comment: So don't append a new header.  Look up the existing one and change it.

Comment: Or remove the old one before you append the new one

Comment: omg you're right! It was that simple!!! i wanted to append a new header because i wanted to use just JS, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `textContent` property of your `h1` when the button is clicked. See the example below.

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#date_heading').textContent = document.querySelector('#date_input').value;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="date_heading">Date</h1>
<input id="date_input" type="date">
<button id="button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, get the h1 element by his id and set it when user presses the button. For example if you want to change innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById("H1_element_Id").innerHTML = "your date here";
```